# How can I add a 2 lines form one variable to a specific line from another variable?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, centos7

I have these variables which outputs:

```
$nw_monitor
Host has 'em3, em2, em1, em4' network devices
em3 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Checking health of 'em2'
Checking health of 'em1'
em4 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Host has 2 healthy network links
```

And the second variable.

```
$link
Speed              : 10 Gb/s
Link status        : yes
Speed              : 10 Gb/s
Link status        : yes
```

From the second variable, it gives the speed and link status for each interface mentioned in $nw_monitor, em2 and em1.

So I would like to mix them so it looks like this:

```
Host has 'em3, em2, em1, em4' network devices
em3 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Checking health of 'em2'
Speed              : 10 Gb/s
Link status        : yes
Checking health of 'em1'
Speed              : 10 Gb/s
Link status        : yes
em4 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Host has 2 healthy network links
```

I have tried this:

```
sed /^Checking/R<(echo "$link") <(echo "$nw_monitor")
```

BUT, I get his output:

```
Host has 'em3, em2, em1, em4' network devices
em3 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Checking health of 'em2'
Speed              : 10 Gb/s
Checking health of 'em1'
Link detected      : yes
em4 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Host has 2 healthy network links
```

Comment: Where do these variable values come from? It would maybe be easier to process the original sources than variables in which they were stored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are they in strings? I think this would be easier in simple files.

```
$: echo "$nw_monitor">a
$: echo "$link">b
$: while read a
>  do echo "$a"
>     case "$a" in Checking*) for c in 1 2; do read b <&3; echo " $b"; done;; esac
>  done <a 3<b
Host has 'em3, em2, em1, em4' network devices
em3 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Checking health of 'em2'
 Speed              : 10 Gb/s
 Link status        : yes
Checking health of 'em1'
 Speed              : 10 Gb/s
 Link status        : yes
em4 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Host has 2 healthy network links
```

But if you just need them in strings...

```
$: while read a
>  do echo "$a"
>     case "$a" in Checking*) for c in 1 2; do read b <&3; echo " $b"; done;; esac
>  done < <(echo "$nw_monitor") 3< <(echo "$link")
Host has 'em3, em2, em1, em4' network devices
em3 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Checking health of 'em2'
 Speed              : 10 Gb/s
 Link status        : yes
Checking health of 'em1'
 Speed              : 10 Gb/s
 Link status        : yes
em4 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Host has 2 healthy network links
```

Comment: Just make sure that data lines up, because I see no way in the info given to verify the lines from `$link` match the lines in `$nw_monitor`.

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- re: `$link` - 1st line of data for a link always contains the string `Speed`
- re: `$link` - OP's sample shows each link has 2 lines of data but we'll assume this could vary
- re: `$nw_monitor` - lines of interest always contain the string `Checking health`
- re: `$nw_monitor` - OP's sample shows 2 sets of link data and 2 `Checking health` lines but we'll assume we could have additional `Checking health` lines without matching link data

Setup:

```
nw_monitor="Host has 'em3, em2, em1, em4' network devices
em3 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Checking health of 'em2'
Checking health of 'em1'
Checking health of 'emXXX'                                    # new; no match in $link
em4 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Host has 2 healthy network links"

link="Speed              : 10 Gb/s
Link status        : yes
Link desc          : random stuff comment string              # new; this link data set consists of 3 lines
Speed              : 10 Gb/s
Link status        : yes"
```

**NOTE:** comments do not exist in the actual data

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v mon="$nw_monitor" -v link="$link" '              # pass bash variables to awk
BEGIN { n=split(link,a,RS)                              # split link on default RS="\n" delimiter, put data in a[] array

        for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {                            # loop through indices of the a[] array
            if (a[i] ~ /Speed/) { linkid++; sep="" }    # if this is a new set of link data then increment our linkid and clear the separator
            links[linkid] = links[linkid] sep a[i]      # append to links[] array
            sep=ORS                                     # set separator to default ORS="\n" for 2nd-nth lines of this link data set
        }

        linkid=0
        n=split(mon,a,RS)                               # split nw_monitor on default RS="\n" delimiter, put data in a[] array (array will be cleared of previous link-related data)

        for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {                            # loop through indices of the a[] array
            print a[i]                                  # print current line
            if (a[i] ~ /Checking health/) {             # if this is a line of interest then ...
               if (++linkid in links)                   # increment linkid and if a valid index of the links[] array then ...
                  print links[linkid]                   # print contents of the associated links[] array
               else
                  print "    WARNING: no link data"
            }
        }
      }
'
```

This generates:

```
Host has 'em3, em2, em1, em4' network devices
em3 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Checking health of 'em2'
Speed              : 10 Gb/s
Link status        : yes
Link desc          : random stuff comment string
Checking health of 'em1'
Speed              : 10 Gb/s
Link status        : yes
Checking health of 'emXXX'
    WARNING: no link data
em4 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Host has 2 healthy network links
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`, maybe:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {link[i++] = $0; next} {print}
  /^Checking health of / {print link[j++]; print link[j++]}
' <( printf '%s\n' "$link" ) <( printf '%s\n' "$nw_monitor" )
```

The `awk` script stores the lines of variable `link` in an indexed (from 0) array also named `link`. When parsing the second variable it simply adds 2 lines of array `link` after any line that starts with `Checking health of` .

The 2 bash process substitutions `<( printf ... )` are a way to turn your variables into something that looks like a file for `awk`.

Comment: Was about to add this, but since you did already, I'll just upvote and move on. :)

Comment: All generated awk arrays, fields, and strings start at 1, not 0, so you should follow that convention for user-defined arrays too to avoid shooting yourself in the foot by forgetting which is which some time.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash):

```
cat <(echo "$link") |
sed -e '/Checking/{R /dev/stdin' -e 'R /dev/stdin' -e '}' <(echo "$nw_monitor")
```

Pass the variable `$link` as standard input and apply two instances of the `R` command for each occurrence of the string `Checking`.

N.B. The `R` command must be terminated by a newline, the option `-e` provides this functionality.

---

Alternative:

```
cat <(echo "$b") | sed -e '/Checking/R /dev/stdin' -e '//R /dev/stdin' <(echo "$a")
```

Comment: UUoC, but that's a neat approach. Kudos.

Comment: `$: sed -e '/Checking/R /dev/stdin' -e '//R /dev/stdin' <(echo "$nw_monitor") <<< "$link"` - 
In GNU `sed` ["The empty regular expression ‘//’ repeats the last regular expression match"](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses). Will that work on non-GNU versions?

Comment: @PaulHodges the '//' is common to all seds however the `R` command is GNU specific.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following `awk` code. This uses variable `link` as first input and variable `nw_monitor` as second input for `awk` program and prints the required output.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/^Speed/){
    value[++i]=$0
    next
  }
  if($0~/^Link status/){
    value[i]=(value[i]?value[i] ORS:"") $0
  }
  next
}
/^Checking/{
  print $0 ORS value[++j]
  next
}
1
'  <( printf '%s\n' "$link" ) <( printf '%s\n' "$nw_monitor" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

nw_monitor="\
Host has 'em3, em2, em1, em4' network devices
em3 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Checking health of 'em2'
Checking health of 'em1'
em4 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Host has 2 healthy network links"

link="\
Speed              : 10 Gb/s
Link status        : yes
Speed              : 10 Gb/s
Link status        : yes"

awk '
    NR == FNR {
        ifaceNr += (NR % 2)
        link[ifaceNr] = (ifaceNr in link ? link[ifaceNr] ORS : "") $0
        next
    }
    FNR == 1 { ifaceNr = 0 }
    { print }
    /^Checking/ { print link[++ifaceNr] }
' <(printf '%s\n' "$link") <(printf '%s\n' "$nw_monitor")
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
Host has 'em3, em2, em1, em4' network devices
em3 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Checking health of 'em2'
Speed              : 10 Gb/s
Link status        : yes
Checking health of 'em1'
Speed              : 10 Gb/s
Link status        : yes
em4 does not have any ip rules, skipping health checks
Host has 2 healthy network links
```